# Labelling Points on a highcharter scatter chart

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I want to label each individual point in a highcharter scatter plot. The below code produces a highcharter chart:

```
library(highcharter)
df = data.frame(name = c("tom", "dick", "harry"), 
           height = c(170L,180L, 185L), 
           weight = c(65L, 68L, 75L))

highchart() %>%
hc_add_series(df, type = "scatter", hcaes(x = weight, y = height), showInLegend = FALSE) %>%
hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "height: {point.y} <br> weight: {point.x}")
```

Hovering over each point shows: "series 1, height: 170, weight: 65" etc.
I want the labels to show "tom, height: 170, weight: 65" when hovering over tom and similarly for dick and harry.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just added group variable in `hcaes`

```
 highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(df,type = "scatter", 
                hcaes(x = weight, y = height, group=name), showInLegend = FALSE) %>%
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "height: {point.y} <br> weight: {point.x}")
```

And it worked well.

From the comments, i suggest another options.

### Option 1

Change `highchart()` to `hchart()`

```
hchart(df,type = "scatter",
       hcaes(x = weight, y = height, group = name),
       showInLegend = FALSE) %>%
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "height: {point.y} <br> weight: {point.x}")
```

### Option 2

Using `marker` option in `hc_add_series`.

```
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(df,type = "scatter", 
                hcaes(x = weight, y = height, group = name),
                showInLegend = FALSE, 
                marker = list(symbol = fa_icon("circle")),
                color = "blue") %>%
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "height: {point.y} <br> weight: {point.x}")
```

Comment: The only problem with that is changing the marker shapes

Comment: M-M is right. This solves one problem but creates another. Does any one know how to force the marker shapes/colors to all be identical?

Comment: Thanks Steve, I've added an extra line to your code to modify the color of the markers to blue