# How to call a script in another script in R

Tags: r, scripting

I have created a series of commands in R that get a job done using a specific URL. I would like to iterate the series of commands over a list of URLS that reside in a separate text file. How do I call the list into the commands one at a time?

I do not know what the proper terminology for this programming action. I've looked into scripting and batch programming but this is not what I want to do.

```
# URL that comes from list
URL <- "http://www.urlfromlist.com"

# Load URL
theurl <- getURL(URL,.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE) )

# Read the tables
tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)

# Create a list
tables <- list.clean(tables, fun = is.null, recursive = FALSE)

# Convert the list to a data frame
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, tables)

# Save dataframe out as a csv file
write.csv(df2, file = dynamicname, row.names=FALSE)
```

The above code is what I am doing. The first variable needs to be a different URL each time from a list - rinse and repeat. Thanks!

UPDATED CODE - this is still not writing out any files but runs.

```
# Function to pull tables from list of URLs
URLfunction<- function(x){
  # URL that comes from list
  URL <- x

  # Load URL
  theurl <- RCurl::getURL(URL,.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE) )

  # Read the tables
  tables <- XML::readHTMLTable(theurl)

  # Create a list
  tables <- rlist::list.clean(tables, fun = is.null, recursive = FALSE)

  # Convert the list to a data frame
  df <- do.call(rbind,tables)

  # Split date and time column out
  df2 <- separate(df, "Date / Time", c("Date", "Time"), sep = " ")

  # Fill the missing column with text, in this case shapename
  shapename <- qdapRegex::ex_between(URL, "ndxs", ".html")
  df2$Shape <- shapename

  # Save dataframe out as a csv file
  write.csv(result, paste0(shapename, '.csv', row.names=FALSE))

  return(df2)
}

URL <- read.csv("PATH", header = FALSE)
purrr::map_df(URL, URLfunction) ## Also tried purrr::map_df(URL[,1], URLfunction)
```

Comment: Is the list of URLs in a text document on your local computer or is it at a URL?

Comment: Hi Andrew, Yes the URLs are in a csv,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly,
my answer could be work with your problem.

#### Used library

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(rlist)
library(purrr)
```

#### Define function

```
URLfunction<- function(x){
# URL that comes from list
URL <- x

# Load URL
theurl <- RCurl::getURL(URL,.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE) )

# Read the tables
tables <- XML::readHTMLTable(theurl)

# Create a list
tables <- rlist::list.clean(tables, fun = is.null, recursive = FALSE)

# Convert the list to a data frame
df <- do.call(rbind,tables)

# Save dataframe out as a csv file

return(df)
}
```

#### Assume you have a data like below

( I am not sure what data  looks like you have )

```
URL <- c("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56139810/how-to-call-a-script-in-another-script-in-r",
         "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56122052/labelling-points-on-a-highcharter-scatter-chart/56123057?noredirect=1#comment98909916_56123057")

result<- purrr::map(URL, URLfunction) 
result <- do.call(rbind, result)
```

#### Write.csv is last step

If you want write.csv by each URL , plz move in to URLfunction

```
write.csv(result, file = dynamicname, row.names=FALSE)
```

### Aditional

#### List version

```
URL <- list("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56139810/how-to-call-a-script-in-another-script-in-r",
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56122052/labelling-points-on-a-highcharter-scatter-chart/56123057?noredirect=1#comment98909916_56123057")


result<- purrr::map_df(URL, URLfunction) 

>result

   asked    today yesterday
1 viewed 35 times      <NA>
2 active    today      <NA>
3 viewed     <NA>  34 times
4 active     <NA>     today
```

#### CSV

```
URL <- read.csv("PATH",header = FALSE)

result<- purrr::map_df(URL[,1], URLfunction) 

>result

   asked    today yesterday
1 viewed 35 times      <NA>
2 active    today      <NA>
3 viewed     <NA>  34 times
4 active     <NA>     today
```

## Add edited version of your code.

```
URLfunction<- function(x){
  # URL that comes from list
  URL <- x
  
  # Load URL
  theurl <- RCurl::getURL(URL,.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE) )
  
  # Read the tables
  tables <- XML::readHTMLTable(theurl)
  
  # Create a list
  tables <- rlist::list.clean(tables, fun = is.null, recursive = FALSE)
  
  # Convert the list to a data frame
  df <- do.call(rbind,tables)
  
  # Split date and time column out
  df2 <- tidyr::separate(df, "Date / Time", c("Date", "Time"), sep = " ")
  
  # Fill the missing column with text, in this case shapename

  shapename <- unlist(qdapRegex::ex_between(URL, "ndxs", ".html"))
  # qdapRegex::ex_between returns list type, when it added to df2 it couldn't be saved. 
  # So i added 'unlist' 

  df2$Shape <- shapename
  
  # Save dataframe out as a csv file
  write.csv(df2, paste0(shapename, '.csv'), row.names=FALSE)
# Here are two error.
# First, You maked the data named 'df2' not 'result'. So i changed result -->df2
# Second, row.names is not the 'paste0' attributes, it is 'write.csv's attributes.  
  return(df2)
}
```

After defining above function,

```
URL = c("nuforc.org/webreports/ndxsRectangle.html",
        "nuforc.org/webreports/ndxsRound.html")

RESULT = purrr::map_df(URL, URLfunction) ## Also tried purrr::map_df(URL[,1], URLfunction)
```

Finally, i get the result below

```
1. Rectangle.csv, Round.csv files on your desktop(Saved path).
2. Returning row binded data frame looks like below (2011 x 8)
> RESULT[1,]
    Date  Time     City State     Shape  Duration
1 5/2/19 00:20 Honolulu    HI Rectangle 3 seconds
                                                                                                                             Summary
1 Several of rectangles connected in different LED like colors.  Such as red, green, blue, etc. ;above Waikiki. ((anonymous report))
  Posted
1 5/9/19
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a csv file of all the urls, but I could try to use the vector shown above.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to run the function but it is not achieving the result. I want to run the function over each URL separately and then write the file out. Please see above the edited code. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure, it's just a list of URLs, see the first two URLs below. However, what I think is happening is that the code is compiling all the URLS into one data frame instead of doing each URL separately and then writing each CSV out per URL. I need to do changes to each URL individually before writing them out. The changes cannot be made because URL is all the links, not one at a time. Let me know.

http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxsRectangle.html, http://www.nuforc.org/webreports/ndxsRound.html

Comment: From your reply, i added new edited version(chnaged a little from your code). It worked well on me!!

Comment: Thanks for those edits. It worked for me too. I really appreciate it!